# Magento 2.4.1 - Static content deployment needed in developer mode

Tags: magento2.4, static-content, static-content-deploy, deployment

I am in the middle of a situation regarding the static content deployment and I find it strange.

I built Magento 2 themes based on Luma/Blank or even not based on those. When I was working under the developer mode, I didn't need to deploy static files after each CSS/JS/PHTML change. This is how the developer mode is supposed to work as far as I know.

However, I also worked with other themes developed by third-party providers, well-known in this industry, but I needed to deploy static files even if I was using the developer mode.

To fix this, I tried to apply different solutions such as:

- remove pub/static/*, excepting the .htaccess file;
- remove var/view_preprocessed/*;
- remove deployed_version.txt.

Is this a theme-related error or am I missing something?

Comment: Are the files inside pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/locale/ and all different subfolders in there, symlinks? Or are they actual files? If they are symlinks, updates should happen automatically, after cleaning the cache if cache is enabled. If not a symlink, try to delete that specific file, go to a page where that file is required, and check again, if the file is created as a symlink, or you get an error that file not found.
Might check on setting up Grunt

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step properly, After all think working with developer mode and all changes effect in fronted without deploy static files every time.

When Magento 2 is not in production mode, it will try to create symlinks for some static resources on local server. We have to change that behavior of Magento 2 by going to edit `ROOT > app > etc > di.xml` file. Open up `di.xml` in your favorite code editor, find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section below, you will find an item `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` which needs to be modified. You can modify it by changing the following content:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

To:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Now last step, also delete old files generated in `ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS`

In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this below step again.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```